# How to securely access the content in AWS cloudfront by using react native

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, signed-url

I have uploaded Images in AWS S3 Bucket. How can we access those private content securely.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to create a lambda@edge function (possible only in the us-east-1 region) that will be triggered by your CloudFront distribution.

Specify a behavior path pattern for example "/images".
To securely access your images, add an authorizer to your lambda function,
you could use Cognito for that, and authenticate users at the front end
(sign-Up/sign-In), using AWS amplify/auth module.